# Online viewing of published iCal calendars

Tags: webapp-rec, icloud, icalendar

I have a webcal URL to an iCal calendar I need to check out.

```
webcal://ical.mac.com/user/schedule.ics
```

Is there an online web service or something that will allow me to see that calendar without having to install anything or register anywhere?

Ultimately I'd like to just give that URL to a web service and get it back as HTML tables or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http://ical.me.com/USERNAME/calendar_name`

eg. `http://ical.me.com/user/schedule`

Comment: Thanks! Was certain there was a way like that, just couldn't figure out how it was :p

Comment: Seems to not work anymore: `Http/1.1 Service Unavailable`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/calendar) to [subscribe to the calendar](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37100), and then view the events on there. You can delete the calendar once you are done viewing it. If you want to see all the events as a list, use the agenda view and only select the calendar you added.

Answer (score 0):

Try [iCal Exchange](http://www.icalx.com/).

> The iCal Exchange was created to give the Internet community an easy way to publish their calendars using the built-in "Publish to a web server" mechanism.
>
> You can publish your calendars here for free. When you share your calendar URLs, visitors will be able to download the .ics file, and even view your calendar through a Web browser. Ordinary WebDAV servers do not have this capability. In addition, we will have advanced features like password-protection for individual calendars.